# Chaining powershell scripts with varying named parameters

Tags: powershell

I have several Powershell scripts which I want to chain together. Each script has some named parameters, and some of these parameters can be shared across scripts.

**a.ps1**

```
param(
    [String]$foo="",
    [String]$bar=""
) 

& "./b.ps1"
```

**b.ps1**

```
param(
    [String]$baz=""
)

& "./c.ps1"
```

**c.ps1**

```
param(
    [String]$thing="",
    [String]$stuff="",
    [String]$baz="",
    [String]$foo=""
)
```

I want to call the first script in this stack with a single list of arguments

```
powershell ./a.ps1 -foo myfoo -bar mybar -baz mybaz -thing mything -stuff mystuff
```

and have each script take what it needs from the parameter list, and then pass the entire list on to the next script, all the way down the chain. The number and order of the parameters in each script can change over time, and this shouldn't have to require changing code in the other scripts. Is this possible? I've tried the usual splatting stuff like `@args`, and that doesn't seem to work (received parameters are all empty). I can combined bound and unbound args with

```
$allArgs = $PsBoundParameters.Values + $args
```

but this arranges all parameters in a fixed sequence that requires each script in the chain to follow the parameter list of its caller.

Edit : The purpose of this exercise to completely obscure the logic within the chain from the point where we call it. I simply provide a list of all parameters required by the entire stack, and each unit script can throw an error if a parameter is invalid.

Comment: "this shouldn't have to require changing code in the other scripts" <- this part is not really possible - if a new parameter is added to `c.ps1`, you'll have to declare them in the calling scripts as well

Answer (score 0):

Create a property bag and pass that.

```
function a ([PSCustomObject] $obj)
{
    "foo: $($obj.foo)"
    "bar: $($obj.bar)"
    
    b @PSBoundParameters 
}

function b ([PSCustomObject] $obj)
{
    "baz: $($obj.baz)"
    
    c @PSBoundParameters 
}

function c ([PSCustomObject] $obj)
{
    "thing: $($obj.thing)"
    "stuff: $($obj.stuff)"
    "baz: $($obj.baz)"
    "foo: $($obj.foo)"
}

$obj = [PSCustomObject]@{
    foo = $null
    bar = $null
    baz = $null
    thing = $null
    stuff = $null
}
  
$obj.foo   = "1" 
$obj.bar   = "2" 
$obj.baz   = "3" 
$obj.thing = "4" 
$obj.stuff = "5" 

a $obj 

# output
foo: 1
bar: 2
baz: 3
thing: 4
stuff: 5
baz: 3
foo: 1
```

However, I don't recommend doing this because it is shortsighted

```
$obj = [PSCustomObject]@{
    foo = $null
    bar = $null
    baz = $null
    thing = $null
    stuff = $null
    foov2 = $null
    barv2 = $null
    bazv2 = $null
    thingv2 = $null
    stuffv2 = $null
    foov3 = $null
    barv3 = $null
    bazv3 = $null
    thingv3 = $null
    stuffv3 = $null
    stuffv3 = $null
}
```

and dangerous.

```
function executeCommand ([PSCustomObject] $obj) { "$($obj.myCommand)" }

$obj = [PSCustomObject]@{
    myCommand = "harmless"
}


# lab
$obj.myCommand   = "format drive" 
executeCommand $obj 

# production
executeCommand $obj
```

Instead, explicitly define and call functions. You might choose to save and reuse variables in scripts. You can dot source functions or create a script-based module.

```
# UtilityFunctions.ps1
function executeCommand ([string] $command, [string] $hostname) { "$command $hostname" }

# lab.ps1
. C:\scripts\UtilityFunctions.ps1

$hostname = "lab"
$command = "format drive"

executeCommand $command $hostname

# production.ps1
. C:\scripts\UtilityFunctions.ps1

$hostname = "production"
$command = "list free space"

executeCommand $command $hostname
```

- [Script scope and dot sourcing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scripts?view=powershell-7.1#script-scope-and-dot-sourcing)
- [How to Write a PowerShell Script Module - PowerShell | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/module/how-to-write-a-powershell-script-module?view=powershell-7.1)

Also, your parameters have a default value of an empty string which probably is not your intent.

```
param(
    [String]$foo="",
    [String]$bar=""
) 

param(
    [String]$foo,
    [String]$bar
)
```

- [default values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions?view=powershell-7.1#named-parameters)

Comment: I updated my question to be clearer about what I'm trying to achieve. The chain should be a black box, and parameters work like an arbitrary list of global variables. If the calling point needs to know how to set each component up, that breaks the black box.